# ¿Como hacer que la formula siguiente: =CONTAR.SI($D$2:D3,D3), se ejecute con ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

La formula me devuelve en cada fila el numero de veces que se va repitiendo el criterio, pero no he logrado ponerla en un ArrayFormula, para no tener que estar copiando la formula cada que se inserta una fila nueva.

Comment: Se puede enumerar pero de forma descendente

Answer (score 1):

Intente este:

```
=ArrayFormula(SI(D2:D="",,CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(D2:D,D2:D,FILA(D2:D),"<="&FILA(D2:D))))
```

Nota: No hablo bien el español. Usé una app para la traducción.